# Examples of Chern number calculations where more than two $U(1)$ gauge of wavefunction has been used

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge, berry-pancharatnam-phase

While computing the Chern number of electronic wave functions
\begin{align}
 \left|\psi\right\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\ \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i \phi} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
on the Bloch Sphere ($S^2$), it turns out that the wave function has singular dependence (vortex singularity) on $\phi$
at $\theta=\pi$. So, we need to choose a different $U(1)$ gauge for $\left|\psi\right\rangle$, so
that the state is well defined at the south pole of the Bloch Sphere. A good choice of
gauge is
\begin{align}
 \left|\psi\right\rangle’ = e^{-i\phi}\left|\psi\right\rangle.
\end{align}
This $\left|\psi\right\rangle’$ is well defined at the south pole. So a single $U(1)$ gauge
for the wave function is not going to work, here we needed two gauges which
are valid on different patches of the Bloch Sphere. This nature of the gauge
is what gives rise to the nonzero Chern number.

Now, in this example, there are two vortex singularities on each pole. **I was trying
to find any examples where there are more singularities on the state manifold.**